# Django and use calculated values in QuerySet

Tags: python, mysql, django, django-queryset

I have a function to convert net to gross price like this.
taxRate is the tax value. e.g. 23, 8, 5, 0

```
def gross(netValue, taxRate: int, currencyPrecision=2):
    if taxRate > 0:
        return round(netValue * (100 + taxRate) / 100, currencyPrecision)
    else:
        return round(netValue, currencyPrecision)
```

In my model I have a class that is order items with fields: netPrice and taxId.

```
class OrderPosition(models.Model):
    posNumber = models.AutoField(auto_created=True, primary_key=True, editable=False, blank=False)
    order = models.ForeignKey(OrderHeader, on_delete=models.PROTECT)
    product = models.ForeignKey(Product, on_delete=models.PROTECT)
    quantity = models.DecimalField(blank=False, max_digits=3, decimal_places=0)
    netPrice = MoneyField(blank=False, max_digits=6, decimal_places=2, default=Money("0", "PLN"))
    taxId = models.IntegerField(blank=False, default=0)
```

The value of the entire order with a given ID can be calculated as follows:

```
    def getNetValue(self):
        posList = OrderPosition.objects.filter(order_id=self.orderID)
        if posList:
            return str(posList.aggregate(netValue=Sum(F('quantity') * F('netPrice'),
                                                      output_field=MoneyField()))['netValue'])
        else:
            return "0"
```

Question: Can I use my function "gross()" in a query to calculate the gross value of an order in a similar way to calculate the net worth?

I suppose the aggregation function is performed on the database side (mySQL in my case) and we can only use what is understandable at the database and SQL level.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
net_value = OrderPosition.objects.filter(order_id=self.order_id).aggregate(
    net_value=Sum(F('quantity') * F('net_price'), output_field=MoneyField())
)['net_value']


tax_rate = OrderPosition.objects.filter(order_id=self.orderID) \
    .values('taxId')[0]['taxId']

gross_value = gross(net_value, tax_rate)
```

we need to iterate over the order item and calculate the gross for each item like this:

```
total_gross_value = Money(0, "PLN")
for order_item in OrderPosition.objects.filter(order_id=self.order_id):
net_price = order_item.net_price
tax_rate = order_item.tax_id
gross_price = gross(net_price, tax_rate)
total_gross_value += gross_price
```

we can use annotate method on queryset like this:

```
from django.db.models import F, Func

class GrossValue(Func):
    function = 'ROUND'
    template = '%(function)s(%(expressions)s * (100 + %(tax_rate)s) / 100, 2)'

    def __init__(self, expression, tax_rate, **extra):
        super().__init__(expression, tax_rate=tax_rate, **extra)

OrderPosition.objects.filter(order_id=self.order_id).annotate(
    gross_price=GrossValue(F('net_price'), F('tax_id'))
).aggregate(Sum('gross_price'))
```

have a nice day ;)

Comment: Unfortunately, this is not the correct solution. Note that if an order has multiple items, each item may have a different tax.